how to handle gradle config file build classes out path change after version upgrade
I have code below with old gradle version, but after upgrade gradle to 8.0, the path changed:
old gradle path is:
${project.buildDir}/intermediates/javac/debug/classes

new gradle changed it to:
intermediates/javac/debug/compileDebugJavaWithJavac/classes

Maybe it will change again after new gradle version updated.
I would like to use some pattern instead of hardcode path to avoid such upgrade breakage.
Any suggestion?
    println "${buildDir}/reports/jacoco/report.xml"
    def kotlinDebugTree = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}/tmp/kotlin-classes/debug", excludes: androidExclusion)
    def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "${project.buildDir}/intermediates/javac/debug/classes", excludes: androidExclusion)
    classDirectories.setFrom(files([debugTree, kotlinDebugTree, debugTree]))

